# Hex editing with C++

Tags: c++

Let's assume I want to change something in the 000F5344 address of an executable. How do I go about it?

Comment: Do you need to do this repetitively / programmatically? Why not use a Hex Editor?

Comment: question: can we use placement new for the above purpose?

Comment: @prabhu: what's placement new?

Comment: @ysap: this could be used to patch/hack a program on the client side.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@Pablo Santa Cruz provides an excellent way, but in C. If you prefer to go pure C++, here's how:

1. Open file: **fstream::open** (remember to use the binary flag)
2. Set the put pointer position: **fstream::seekp**
3. Write data at the put pointer position: **fstream::put**
4. Close file: **fstream::close**

This is by no means better than the C version though.

Comment: This only replaces the offsets first 2 hex's, eg: Offset "0x1324" starts with "12 34" (hex), I want to make it "44 44", but it only makes it "44 34"

Answer (score 11):

Four steps solution follows:

1. Open the file with **binary** flag (use `fopen`).
2. Move to the address (**offset**) (use `fseek`).
3. Write your data (use `fwrite`).
4. Close the file (use `fclose`).

Use google to get help on the four mentioned functions calls. Will also work in **C**.

Comment: Just for correctness, wouldn't that be fseek instead of ftell?